# How to create xmlNode which will always be parsed as array when converted into JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xsd, jsonschema

I have this simple yet tricky requirement.
My code derives some xml form source which can be like this
**XML1**

```
<data>
    <MyDataCollection>
        <mydata>
            <m1>dsds</m1>
        </mydata>
        <mydata>
            <m1>dsds</m1>
        </mydata>
    </MyDataCollection>
</data>
```

or this
**XML2**

```
<data>
    <MyDataCollection>
        <mydata>
            <m1>dsds</m1>
        </mydata>
    </MyDataCollection>
</data>
```

When I convert these two type of XMLs into JSON, 
I get following output for XML1
**JSON1**

```
{
  "data": {
    "MyDataCollection": {
      "mydata": [
        { "m1": "dsds" },
        { "m1": "dsds" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and following output for XML2
**JSON2**

```
{
  "data": {
    "MyDataCollection": {
      "mydata": { "m1": "dsds" }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to validate these two JSONs with same JSON schema.

The JSON schema for both of these JSON are different and throws
`"Expected Array but got Object"` or

```
"Expected Object but got Array"
```

depending on whether it was made using JSON with Array(1st JSON) or JSON with Object(2nd JSON)

So I want something which would always parse `MyDataCollection` as an Array whenever converted into JSON irrespective of the fact that it has one or more child elements.

There is one workaround to this by adding a Dummy `<mydata>` tag in `<MyDataCollection>` but it's not feasible with my requirement.

Is there any attribute which I can specify in XML tag, which would always interpret it as an Array whenever parsed?

Comment: You haven't said which tools you are using for XML to JSON conversion. They are all different, and none of them has a good answer to this problem because there's a basic mismatch between the XML and JSON data models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **XSLT 3.0** to convert the XML to JSON, you can use the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <!-- CONVERT INPUT TO XML FOR JSON -->
    <xsl:variable name="xml">
        <map>
            <map key="data">
                 <map key="MyDataCollection">
                    <array key="mydata">
                        <xsl:for-each select="MyDataCollection/mydata">
                            <map>
                                <string key="m1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="m1"/>
                                </string>
                            </map>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </array>
                </map>
            </map>
        </map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($xml)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

```
{"data":{"MyDataCollection":{"mydata":[{"m1":"dsds"},{"m1":"dsds"}]}}}
```

from your **XML1** example and:

```
{"data":{"MyDataCollection":{"mydata":[{"m1":"dsds"}]}}}
```

from **XML2**.

---

Demo1: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNyd
Demo2: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNyd/1